# How do I do tensor integrals?

Tags: numerical-integration, tensors

I am reading hydrodynamics and tensor integrals appear very often in this topic. So I want to learn how do I do these tensor integrals in Mathematica. In the following, I am writing the simplest possible integral appearing in the subject.

1. $\int d^4x~x^\mu~~~~~~~~~~~$ [here, $\mu$ runs from 1 to 4]
2. $\int\frac{d^4x}{x^\nu y_\nu} x^\mu~~~~~~~~~~~$ [here, $y$ is independent of $x^\mu$]

Comment: Your integrals don't converge, so it's not clear what output you expect from mathematica.

Comment: At first I want to know how do I write these integral codes in mathematica. Say I will put some limit in the integrations. I am totally new in mathematica. So I want to whether I can solve this type integrals directly or there is some other method for such tensorial integrals.

Comment: Well, what about `v[μ_Integer] := Integrate[x[μ],{x[1],0,1},{x[2],0,1},{x[3],0,1},{x[4],0,1}]`?

Comment: The $\mu$ within the square braces, how does it function? It it a kind of label or something else? (I can see the logic in your writing. I will let you know after I try that out)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) functionality. For example, suppose the integration range is from 0 to 1 in each coordinate. Then:

```
Integrate[x, x ∈ Cuboid[{0,0,0,0}, {1,1,1,1}]]
```

> {1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}

Your second integral is much harder (i.e., it takes more time), but still possible, e.g.:

```
y = {1,1,1,1};
Integrate[1/x.y x, x ∈ Cuboid[{0,0,0,0}, {1,1,1,1}]]
```

> {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}

Comment: OP almost certainly is using a non-euclidean metric, likely with signature (+++-) or (---+), so the `x.y` in the denominator is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty While correct, it would be a trivial matter to incorporate those signatures into `y`.